# Creating permuations of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, permutation, cartesian-product

I would like to take a list of dictionaries and create a new list of permutations in a specific format.

For example, I've got a list below with dictionaries in it. I would like to create all possible lists using these items in a specific format:
(e.g. result=[dict of type A, dict of type B, dict of type B, dict of type C, dict of type C, dict of Type D, dict of type E, dict of type F]) where the two items of type B cannot be equal and the two items of type C cannot be equal. I will be processing a large set of items so any tips on how to process the permutations more efficiently would be helpful.

```
{'Items':[
{'Name':'name10','Type':'A','measure1':20,'measure2':20},
{'Name':'name20','Type':'A','measure1':25,'measure2':30},
{'Name':'name30','Type':'B','measure1':15,'measure2':40},
{'Name':'name40','Type':'B','measure1':20,'measure2':50},
{'Name':'name50','Type':'B','measure1':25,'measure2':60},
{'Name':'name60','Type':'C','measure1':15,'measure2':70},
{'Name':'name70','Type':'C','measure1':20,'measure2':80},
{'Name':'name80','Type':'C','measure1':25,'measure2':90},
{'Name':'name90','Type':'D','measure1':10,'measure2':30},
{'Name':'name85','Type':'D','measure1':15,'measure2':30},
{'Name':'name75','Type':'E','measure1':53,'measure2':30},
{'Name':'name65','Type':'E','measure1':10,'measure2':30},
{'Name':'name55','Type':'F','measure1':56,'measure2':10},
{'Name':'name45','Type':'F','measure1':10,'measure2':20}
]}
```

Comment: Maybe something like this could help? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you'd like this to look like? Something like `{"A": [{"Name": "name10",  {"measure1" :"20"}, {"Name": "name20",  {"measure1" :"30"}]}`?

Comment: I don't get where permutations come into this.  Are you just removing/merging duplicates?

Comment: I'd like to see a result that's going to be many sets a list of dicts: [[{'Name':'name10','Type':'A','measure1':20,'measure2':20},{'Name':'name30','Type':'B','measure1':15,'measure2':40},{'Name':'name50','Type':'B','measure1':25,'measure2':60},{'Name':'name60','Type':'C','measure1':15,'measure2':70},{'Name':'name80','Type':'C','measure1':25,'measure2':90},{'Name':'name85','Type':'D','measure1':15,'measure2':30},{'Name':'name65','Type':'E','measure1':10,'measure2':30},{'Name':'name45','Type':'F','measure1':10,'measure2':20}], etc...]

Comment: @roippi I think of permuatations when I think of creating all possible combinations of a set of items in a specific order. That's what I'd like to do, but filter out the sets that are repeating objects.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Thats along the lines of what I'm looking for except that I want to create all possible sets and not just one single random set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your dictionary of Items is in the variable `x`:

```
x_set = set((i['Name'], i['Type'], i['measure1'], i['measure2']) for i in x['Items'])
items = [{'Name': i[0], 'Type': i[1], 'measure1': i[2], 'measure2': i[3]} for i in sorted(x_set)]
new_x = {'Items': items}
```

It would have been nice to simply take the set() of dictionaries but that's not possible in Python.  The dictionaries had to be unpacked into tuples, and repacked into dictionaries.

To handle large sets of items, consider breaking them into "shards" based on Name or Type.

Comment: what I'm doing right now is the following, breaking down the large list of dicts into smaller lists of dicts seperated by type with 'a_s = filter(lambda (d): d['Type'] == 'A', listDict)' and then looping through each one with for loops, like this: 'for f in first:
    for s in second:
        for t in third:
            result.append([f, s, t])' and then appending all of the results from the for loops to my result.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by breaking them into shards/groups by Type.